# Using groupBy in Laravel resource

Tags: laravel

I want to pass a collection with a `groupBy` in laravel resource, But the problem is when i use that with `collection` method I can not modify the json and it throws a error:

**PostResource:**

```php
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'comments' => CommentResource::collection($this->comments->groupBy('star')),
    ];
}
```

> Property [star] does not exist on this collection

But as soon as I remove the groupBy method from the collection it works. So how to get and modify the resource when it is grouped by with a specific key ?

Comment: As the error says, does 'star' exist? Have you tried dd($this->comments) ?

Comment: As i said when i take the ```groupBy``` from the chain it would work and ```$this->comments``` returns a collection, the problem is groupBy wrap a comment collection into ```star``` key and hence the resource class doesnt know that key (i think)

Comment: maybe you need to access the relation and not the collection by putting `()` after `comments`.  `$this->comments()->groupBy('star')->get()`

Comment: @BizzyBob The error has gone by using that, But the json is not group by anything.

Comment: @Mwthreex it does not create the `star` key for you. The key must exist within the collection and it "groups" it by that key. So `star` must exist.

Comment: @AnsellCruz It does, Because the ```$this->comments->groupBy('star')``` will work when i use it without ```CommentResource``` class and will groups it by ```star``` key.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"You could possibly group the collection once it has been created."

```php
CommentResource::collection($this->comments)->collection->groupBy('star')
```

credits goes to [devcircus](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/30339#issuecomment-544166366) with his answer on github

Answer (score 0):

i use it and work successfully

```
CommentResource::collection($this->comments)->collection->groupBy('star')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).